# Save the Input value as a hint

Tags: angular, forms, angular4-forms

I am using angular 4. I develop a form its working fine but the problem i am facing is that when i tried to enter any value in the text box it show the last inputted value which i mentioned in that field earlier. Like if i mention any Muhammad and after refreshing the page i am again going for filling the form for next record when i tried to enter the name in the list below it show Muhammad in name field[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-effbud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Show your code otherwise you get negative votes for this question. Despite of demo.

Comment: You can check it by opening the above link

Comment: <div class=" form-group col-md-3 label-floating ">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Nom_Fst">First Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="50" type="text" class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="Nom_Fst" name="Nom_Fst" />
                  </div>

Comment: @AlokeT this one is the code which i use for First Name

Comment: code is also mentioned in the demo plz open the link

Comment: you can use FormControl for this which have several functions. look it here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Answer (score 0):

To disable autofill in the apps:

```
Open the Chrome app.
Tap the Chrome menu button represented by three vertically aligned dots.
Select Settings.
Tap Autofill and Payments.
Toggle the slider next to Autofill Forms to the Off position.
```